# Factorial stream SML

Tags: sml

```
datatype 'a stream =
    Nil
  | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a stream);

exception Bad of string;

fun from seed next = Cons (seed, fn () => from (next seed) next);

fun head (Nil) = raise Bad "got nil in head"
  | head (Cons (h, t)) = h;

fun tail (Nil) = raise Bad "got nil in tail"
  | tail (Cons (h, t)) = t ();

fun take 0 stream = []
  | take n (Nil) = raise Bad "got nil in take"
  | take n (Cons (h, t)) = h :: (take (n - 1) (t ()));
```

I am try to write an infinite factorial stream, where it takes two stream and outputs one stream.

```
fun fac(a,b) = Cons(a, fn() => fac(b, a*(b-1));
```

This is what I have so far. But it does not give me the right answer.

Comment: SML doesn't have any built-in notion of stream.  What is an infinite factorial stream and what does it mean to say that it is a function of two streams? What is `Cons`? Please clarify your question.

Comment: What does it give vs what you expect? And have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it makes sense for a factorial stream to take any inputs, since factorials form a specific sequence.

Instead, you need a helper function that manages the internal state (*n* and *n*!), and then the stream itself is just a value:

```
local
   (* returns a stream consisting of
      nFac,
      nFac * nextN,
      nFac * nextN * (nextN + 1),
      nFac * nextN * (nextN + 1) * (nextN + 2),
      ...
    *)
   fun facHelper (nFac, nextN) = Cons (nFac, fn () => facHelper (nFac * nextN, nextN + 1))
in
   (* a stream consisting of 0!, 1!, 2!, 3!, ... *)
   val factorials = facHelper (1, 1)
end
```

Alternatively, you can create a stream of the numbers 1, 2, 3, …, and a stream-reducer that, given a stream *s*, returns a stream of 1, *s*<sub>1</sub>, *s*<sub>1</sub>*s*<sub>2</sub>, *s*<sub>1</sub>*s*<sub>2</sub>*s*<sub>3</sub>, …:

```
local
  (* returns a stream consisting of n, n + 1, n + 2, n + 3, ... *)
  fun positiveIntegersHelper n = Cons (n, fn () => positiveIntegersHelper (n + 1))
in
  (* a stream consisting of 1, 2, 3, 4, ... *)
  val positiveIntegers = positiveIntegersHelper 1
end

(* Note: the above could also have been written using your 'from' function, as
      val positiveIntegers = from 1 (fn n => n + 1)
 *)

(* given a function f, an initial value seed, and a stream consisting of [s1, s2, s3, ...],
   returns a stream consisting of
   [seed, f(s1, seed), f(s2, f(s1, seed)), f(s3, f(s2, f(s1, seed))), ...]
   -- so, somewhat analogous to List.foldl, except that it returns a stream of all partial
   results, instead of just the final result.
 *)
fun reduceStream _ seed Nil = Cons (seed, fn () => Nil)
  | reduceStream f seed (Cons (h, tf)) =
       Cons (seed, fn () => reduceStream f (f (h, seed)) (tf ()))

(* a stream consisting of 0!, 1!, 2!, 3!, ... *)
val factorials = reduceStream op* 1 positiveIntegers
```